# GMail app in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: gmail, messaging-menu

I'm confused about what application that installs the GMail icon in the Message menu (see link to picture).

[image]

I'm developing my own GMail notification app, so I want to get rid of it.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is icon of `unity-webapps-gmail` application. Just remove it and log out for applying changes.

Also you can manage Message Menu from `dconf-editor`.
 
Open this editor and find `com.canonical.indicator.messages`. In `applications` section you can edit list of applications you want to display.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it (dconf-editor). There must be a bug in the web-apps installer. I tried a few times to install and uninstall (and restarted the shell) with no success. However, after removing GMailmailgooglecom.desktop from com.canonical.indicator.messages, it was solved. One issue remain: the GMail app still show up in the dash. Interestingly, it still works, i.e. a browser window star mail.google.com.

Answer (score 0):

You probably added GMail webapp to your launcher on the left hand side. Remove it and GMail   should also disappear in the Messaging Menu.
In order to do so, right click the GMail icon on the launcher and choose "Remove from the launcher".